# Is the length (in characters) of a token policy id always the same?

Tags: native-assets, policy

Let's say I have the following native token *unit* `d5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756433323639` that consists of the *policy id* `d5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc` and *asset name* `537061636542756433323639`.

The *asset name* is a HEX representation of the name. Therefore it can vary in length.

But the *policy id* is some sort of a hash of the policy, so I'd assume the length of the string is always the same. Is this correct?

What I want to achieve is to split the *asset name* and the *policy id* e.g. like this:

```
'd5e6bf0500378d4f0da4e8dde6becec7621cd8cbf5cbb9b87013d4cc537061636542756433323639'.substring(56)
> "537061636542756433323639"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `policyId` is the hash of the policy script. It is a blake2b-224 hash resulting in 28 bytes and a hex length of 56 chars. So, your code will always work and is the right way to do it.

Find the spec defining the scriptHash [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/683bef2e40cbd10339452c9f2009867c855baf1a/shelley-ma/shelley-ma-test/cddl-files/shelley-ma.cddl#L251), note that the `scriptHash` is of type hash28 denoting the hash length.

Also, the `assetName` can be of any length between 0-32 bytes. Something to keep a note of in your application, this also means that there can be a token without `assetName`. Find the `assetName` length spec [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/683bef2e40cbd10339452c9f2009867c855baf1a/shelley-ma/shelley-ma-test/cddl-files/shelley-ma.cddl#L252)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the policy ID is indeed defined as a `ScriptHash` in the specifications. Its length is 28 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Coud you provide a link to the specification you mentioned?

Comment: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger-specs/blob/683bef2e40cbd10339452c9f2009867c855baf1a/shelley-ma/shelley-ma-test/cddl-files/shelley-ma.cddl#L251